# Changing date format with script

Tags: echo

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line; do
echo "$line"
date=$(echo "$line" | cut -d/ -f1 )
month=$(echo "$line" | cut -d/ -f2 )
echo $month"/"$date"/2017"
done < ~/Downloads/Dates.csv
```

But I get output as //2017 instead of 03/02/2017(example) not sure why date and month field are not populated

Here is the sample ouput[![enter image description here][1]][1]

{
//2017

//2017

//2017

//2017
}

Comment: Don't you think that depends on what's inside `~/Downloads/Dates.csv`?

Comment: It just has date columns like 01/02/2017 03/04/2017 so on. One date for each line

Comment: Then it works for me.

Comment: I just get  / / 2017 / / 2017. I'm not seeing the month and date in output. Does $month need some library to work? I'm new to scripting so please help

Comment: you may be looking for this `while IFS='/' read d m y; do echo ${m}/${d}/${y}; done<~/Downloads/Dates.csv`

Comment: I just tried your method while IFS='/' read d m y; do echo ${m}/${d}/${y}; done<~/Downloads/Dates.csv    I just get output as  //  //  //  I don't why I don't see month or date field. There is some issue with reading "$" fields

Comment: try another bash session , close and open again your terminal, pfnuesel answer is clearly working , something wrong with your shell !

Comment: In your output you do not even see the output from `echo "$line"`. There's something wrong with your input.

Comment: try this one `env -i bash -c 'while IFS='/' read d m y; do echo "${d}/${m}/${y} ${m}/${d}/${y}"; done<~/Downloads/Dates.csv'`

Comment: Still same issue "$line" not shown in output. I'm new to scripting and just opened the terminal and  did vi script.sh saved and using commmand ./script.sh. Are we required to run some libraries or so before ? Thanks a lot for your patience and help here

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text)

Comment: please post a sample of the **input**.  edit your question and paste in the TEXT, not an image.  format it as code with the `{}` icon in the editor.  it's impossible to tell what your script will do without a sample of the actual input.

Comment: I edited the question. My input csv file has 11/12/2017, 01/02/2016/ 1/13/2017

Comment: What is the output of `cat ~/Downloads/Dates.csv`?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what's wrong with your script, since it works for me. But there are easier, better and safer ways to do what you want to do, e.g.

```
awk -F/ '{ OFS="/"; print($2,$1,$3) }' ~/Downloads/Dates.csv
```

If this doesn't work either, or if you want to know why your script doesn't produce the expected output, you have to edit your question and be more specific about what your input looks like.

Comment: Edited the question, please check. I tried your method to but I get output as  //   //  //   Just slashes no date or month or year